# setting up freebsd kerberos key server windows client log in musts

Tags: windows, authentication, freebsd, kerberos

Very few texts talk about

a unix key server
a client windows (lets say XP) to authenticate.

The texts that I have read will mention this topic but more or less skip the details. When setting up/compiling/building/etc a unix (say freebsd) key server, what are the "musts"

a couple of words have been thrown down with the type of authentication/encryption needed but never enough detail.

I haven't been able to find a a good resource for this or posts in mailing lists

help/ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has written [step-by-step descriptions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742433.aspx) on how to integrate a Windows 2000 AD with a Kerberos realm.

Comment: I have found lots of text describing how to have a *nix client authenticate against AD. However I want to have a *nix server be the authentication service. Clients may be windows but all my services run on *nix machines (usually free/openbsd and linux)

Comment: I will clarify a little more. I have a couple of XP workstations, is it known if the step by step would work on XP Home (or possible Pro).

Comment: What would you like this procedure to do? Work at the Windows login? Or work with a separate program after you have logged in locally?

Comment: I would like to have the windows login process authenticate against my Kerberos service.

Comment: For that, I don't think a Kerberos service is sufficient. You need a full Active Directory, and you need the computer to be member of the Active Directory domain. Supposedly, Samba 4 will provide that functionality some day, but it may not work today.